# YUI Datatable to JS object

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui, yahoo

I have a problem. I have YUI DataTable and i need convert it to JS object. But I'm not found standart ways for this. If anyone know, how to solve this problem - please answer.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since YUI 3.5.0 you just need to do `datatable.get('data').toJSON()`. `datatable.get('data')` now returns a `Y.ModelList` which in turn has a `toJSON` method.